# why output all the xml data in only one row

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, url

I'm working on a url to get XML data and make it a dataframe. I tried the following code:

```
fileURL <- "https://data.ny.gov/apI/views/ngbt-9rwf2/legedr.xml" 
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(getURL(fileURL)))
plantcat <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue)) 
plantcat_df <- data.frame(t(plantcat),row.names=NULL)
View(plantcat_df)
```

But my output is all in one row, with thousands columns. Is there any way I can break them into different columns?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have used xmlSApply() at wrong node.
Following code work. just only need to replace the local path with your URL.

```
library("XML")

xml <- xmlParse("D:/rows.xml")
xmltop = getNodeSet(xml, "//response/row/row")
plantcat <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue)) 
plantcat_df <- data.frame(t(plantcat),row.names=NULL)
View(plantcat_df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you@hieu.do. This is a good approach, but I want to load it directly from URL to the r rather than using the local path.

Comment: Use `readLines`: `xmlParse(readLines(url))`

Comment: @YuriRolimus I did specify that you can replace the the section load from file with yours from URL. I load from file only for testing purpose. also please mark as answer if it help you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website, it uses a `SODA API` for their datasets. You can use `RSocrata` package to retrieve them by running the code `install.packages("RSocrata")` and then you can simply call the package and use the unique dataset key to retrieve the dataset through `R`.

```
library(RSocrata)

#list all the available dataset in the website
list.datasets <- RSocrata::ls.socrata("https://data.ny.gov")

# retrieve the data using the unique dataset key "ngbt-9rwf"
df <- RSocrata::read.socrata("https://data.ny.gov/d/ngbt-9rwf")
```